# helm chart error can't evaluate field Values in type interface {}

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I know this is some kind of syntax/yaml structure related error but the message is so cryptic I have no idea what the issue is:

```
Error: render error in "mychart/templates/ingress.yaml": template: mychart/templates/ingress.yaml:35:37: executing "mychart/templates/ingress.yaml" at <.Values.network.appP...>: can't evaluate field Values in type interface {}
```

This is in my values.yaml:

```
network:
  appPort: 4141
```

This is the ingress.yaml:

```
{{- $fullName := include "mychart.fullname" . -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "mychart.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ .Values.network.appPort }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Why doesn't `{{ .Values.network.appPort }}` work? I have used values with this same structure in other places

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Isn't it just scope issue?

Try something as below

```
{{- $fullName := include "mychart.fullname" . -}}
{{- $networkAppPort  := .Values.network.appPort -}}
...
.... omitted code
...
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $networkAppPort }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: hmm can you explain this? I cant find good docs that explain this scoping related stuff. In another template (service.yaml) I dont define a var like that at the top of the yaml file and I can just do `{{ include "bombora-atlantis.fullname" . }}` directly throughout the file and it just works- whats different about the ingress.yaml?

Comment: @red888 Maybe [setting-the-scope-of-a-template](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#setting-the-scope-of-a-template) and [modifying-scope-using-with](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#modifying-scope-using-with). it's pretty hard to say why it works in your case but I assume you simply pass a scope (`.`) to the include.

Comment: The urls above have changed. Current location of Helm scope documentation [control-structures](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

Answer (score 41):

In the range block `.` refers to the current value in the execution time. Instead of `.` you can use `$` to access to the root data object in the range block instead of declaring top level variables.

Example:

```yaml
  {{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ $host }}
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend
              port:
                number: {{ $.Values.frontend.service.port }}
  {{- end}}
```

Comment: IMO That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `$` is actually documented in Helm documentation, but I found it hard to find. 

Its in https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/


"However, there is one variable that is always global - $ - this variable will always point to the root context. This can be very useful when you are looping in a range and you need to know the chart's release name."

Comment: worked for me. I was using `.Release.Name` inside range, just adding $ fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The accepted answer doesn't provide an explanation

Answer (score 7):

I use helm3 and I have the same error message, when i run `helm template my-chart`. In my case, i have define wrongly in `values.yaml`,

**WRONG configuration** (In my `values.yaml` missing `path` under `paths`):

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

  hosts:
    - host: "dev"
      paths:
      - /dev(/|$)(.*)
  tls: []
```

correct the ingress definition like this , it works

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

  hosts:
    - host:
      paths:
      - path: "/dev(/|$)(.*)"
  tls: []
```

my ingress template, `ingress.yaml`, which is generated automatically via helm

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "bsb-lookup.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "bsb-lookup.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

for YAML it is also required to have the immediate parent of any optional value.

Like you are trying to do a check "a.b.c" in some yaml during helm build its gives similar error. it is required to have a.b at least in the default values.yaml.

Solved by going details in - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5435