# Helm Concat tamplate parameter which passed from yaml pipeline

Tags: templates, variables, kubernetes-helm, string-concatenation

I have several yaml files which I try to generalize.

I have `util.tpl`:

```
{{- define "pod-test" -}}
{{- if eq .Values.appName.properties.name  "m1" }}
x: {{.Values.appName.properties.x }}
{{- end }}
```

I would like to make the `appName` string in the `Values.appName.properties.x` dynamic.

I call this template from the destination YAML

```
{{- include "pod-test" . (list "app-name") | indent 2}}
```

but I can't find a way to concat to something like :

```
 {{- $arg1 := index . 0 }}
    {{.Values.{{ $arg1 }}.properties.x }}
```

This just doesn't work what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Will not work on helm. Instead, you can use the `index` function. From this:

```
{{ .Values.{{ .app-name }}.properties.x }}
```

To this:

```
{{ (index .Values .app-name).properties.x }}
```

Keep in mind that `.Values[.app-name]` should exist or else it will throw an error because it will try to access a property from a `nil` object. What you can do is the enclose it in an if-block checking for property existence.

```
{{ if has .Values .index }}
  {{ (index .Values .app-name).properties.x }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i updated the question with adding the {{- $arg1 := index . 0 }}
but it still dosn't work when i try :
{{- if eq index (.Values  .$arg1).properties.name  "m1" }} its not working 
getting :  at <index>: wrong number of args for index: want at least 1 got 0

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing with 
`{{- $arg1 := index . 0 }}`
What are you trying to get? Also your parenthesis are in the wrong position. It should be:
`{{- if eq (index .Values $arg1).properties.name "m1" }}`

Comment: I realized that the code i wrote was wrong since the index was outside of the parenthesis, updated it to be correct. Please lmk if it works

Comment: Thanks! the $arg1 is the variable value im passing into the template  , this value is the dynamic part of the full name of th epipeline . And way im gettng this error :
executing "pod-test" at <.Values>: can't evaluate field Values in type []interface {}

Comment: From a quick search, it looks like a scoping issue. Maybe you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671452/helm-chart-error-cant-evaluate-field-values-in-type-interface

If you still need help, can you update your code so I see how you're passing the value and how you're defining the template