# ingress variables syntax from values.yaml

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a simple api that I've been deploying to K8s as a NodePort service via Helm. I'm working to add an ingress to the Helm chart but I'm having some difficulty getting the variables correct

values.yaml

```
ingress:
  metadata:
    name: {}
    labels: {}
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: "testapi.local.dev"
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: {}
              port: 
                number: 80
```

templates/ingress.yaml, showing only the spec section where I'm having issues.

```
spec:
    rules:
      {{- range .Values.ingress.spec.rules }}
      - host: {{ .host | quote }}
        http:
          paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
            - path: {{ .path | quote }}
              pathType: {{ .pathType | quote }}
              backend:
                service:
                  name: {{ include "testapi.service.name" . }}
                  port:
                  {{- range $key, $value := (include "testapi.deployment.ports" . | fromYaml) }}
                    number: {{ .port }}
                  {{- end}}
           {{- end}}
         {{- end}}
```

When running `helm template` it just leaves these values blank and I'm not sure where the syntax is wrong. Removing the `{{- range .paths }}` and the following `.path` and `.pathType` and replacing them with the value corrects the issue

```
spec:
    rules:
      - host: "testapi.local.dev"
        http:
          paths:
```

Comment: When you call `include`, it's inside a `range` loop, and the special variable `.` is the `paths` item.  Saving `.` outside the loop or using `$` as the parameter will probably help.  [helm chart error can't evaluate field Values in type interface {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671452/helm-chart-error-cant-evaluate-field-values-in-type-interface) is a similar problem (even involving a `range` loop in an Ingress object) and there's a little more discussion there.

Comment: Shouldn't `{{- range .paths }}` be `{{- range .http.paths }}`?

Answer (score 0):

Comments revealed I should be using `{{- range .http.paths }}`.